# UINavigationController with UIHostingController correct way to navigate between screens

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have an existing app build with UIKit, Storyboards and existing `UINavigationController`. I want to add SwiftUI screens using `UIHostingController`, from this screen I want to navigate to another one. I embedded my Views in `NavigationView` and learned that now there are two navigation bar titles. I removed the `NavigationView` and just used `navigationLink` without it. I found out I can set navigation title on the hostingVC before I present it and with `navigationTitle` modifier, but they are changing the same thing.

How does this work and what should I use for navigation inside `UIHostingController`, should I build some custom UIKit solution for navigation?

Comment: Check out Use SwiftUI with UIKit from #wwdc22
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10072

Comment: There is nothing about navigation

Comment: @MeaganS. Not exacly. I have temporarily created a View extension that creates a ViewControllerProvider, adds it to the view's environment, and then returns the view in the UIHostingController. You can then access the UINavigationController inside the view and do something with it. But that created a problem because it became `some View` and I could not check if something was inside the navigation stack. I found https://gist.github.com/michaelhenry/945fc63da49e960953b72bbc567458e6 and just used that for now. I do not know if that is the correct way, but it looks like it could work.